# Assign Command line arguments to a variable in for loop in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following bash code:

```
for (( i=4; i<=$var; ))
do
    temp=`echo $i`
done
```

I need to assign the command line argument stored in $4 to the variable temp which is not happening.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but it seems like you want `temp=$4`.

Comment: Prior to adding an echo you should put all your commands in the variable then echo the information

Comment: Why would you use a loop if you only need to work with `$4`?

Comment: i have a feeling what he *really* wants is to loop through all the command line args

Answer (score 1):

Given a variable `i=4` you can get the value of `$4` using `${!i}`:

```
set -- foo bar baz thisOne etc
i=4
echo "${!i}"
```

This prints the fourth positional parameter, `thisOne`.